# How to add a colon within an php array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below code written by X programmer. I am modifying it.

```
Config::registerSites(
                array(
                        /** -- Site Defaults -- * */
                        "defaults" => array(
                                "site_name" => "some name",
                                "owner" => "Some Owner",
                                "copyright" => "Some Copywrite",
                                "site_version" => "1.0",
                                "mobile" => true

                        ),
                        /** -- Frontend -- * */
                        "frontend" => array(
                                "mysite" => array(
                                        "site_name" => "some name",
                                        "testing" => array("test.somesite.com" => "desktop", "m.test.somesite.com" => "mobile"),
                                        "live" => array("staging.somesite.com" => "desktop", "m.somesite.com" => "mobile"),
                                        "mobile" => true,
                                        "default_locale" => "gb"
                                )
                        )
)
```

I want to add https:// in front of the URL. Like shown below.

```
Config::registerSites(
                array(
                        /** -- Site Defaults -- * */
                        "defaults" => array(
                                "site_name" => "some name",
                                "owner" => "Some Owner",
                                "copyright" => "Some Copywrite",
                                "site_version" => "1.0",
                                "mobile" => true

                        ),
                        /** -- Frontend -- * */
                        "frontend" => array(
                                "mysite" => array(
                                        "site_name" => "some name",
                                        "testing" => array("https://test.somesite.com" => "desktop", "https://m.test.somesite.com" => "mobile"),
                                        "live" => array("https://www.somesite.com" => "desktop", "https://m.somesite.com" => "mobile"),
                                        "mobile" => true,
                                        "default_locale" => "gb"
                                )
                        )
)
```

When I try to access the page from the browser using this URL https://www.somesite.com I get error and URL in the browser shows https//www.somesite.com The colon (:) is removed. What am I doing wrong?

Please, can you help folks?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, so the issue isn't anything to do with code. Simply the website does weird stuff when you visit it with https?

Comment: Does this happen with all URLs, or just this specific website? Can you name the site?

Comment: George Appleton, it is not about https it is about the (:) Even if I add http: it will not work. If I keep the array as www.something.com the site will work fine.

Comment: Barmar, it is the http: or https: the colon is a issue, If I leave it to www.somesite.com it works. I am aware that for some reason I am unable to escape colon (:)

Comment: So for "testing" and "live" you want to prepend the keys with `https://`?

Comment: Yes that is right @The Fourth bird

Comment: @user10591892 Perhaps something like https://3v4l.org/r3d5r

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks for the quick code. The issue is the system is too large and I do not know where this programmer is using the array. Hence, I am left with modifying the code that I have displayed in my question. All I want to know is if there is any way to escape (:) colon in the array I have.

Comment: @user10591892 I'd look at Programmer X's implementation of Config::registerSites or at the location where said configuration is consumed.  There's likely a url-parsing issue when reading from the array.  A colon character in PHP string is not special, reserved, or in need of escaping.